# Moore state machine and Karnaugh map of output

Tags: digital-logic, karnaugh-map

In the Moore state machine if we want to find the output we create a Karnaugh Map of present states and input.  Why?  The output of the Moore machine by definition doesnt depend on the input so we shouldnt include the input in the Karnaugh map. Or have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 1):

For a Moore machine the inputs (as well as the current state) determine the next state, so you need some kind of truth table or state transition table that includes the inputs. For a Moore machine the outputs depend only on the state so a truth table just for the outputs need not include the inputs.

For a Mealy machine both the next state and the current values of the outputs depend on the input, so both the state transition table and the output truth table must include the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The Moore machine output does depend on the input but only on what the state of the input was at the previous clock transition. The Mealy machine input can affect the output even between clock transitions.

Answer (score 0):

The Moore FSM outputs are determined by the state.

And the Moore state is determined, after a clock, by the inputs and the current state.

So the Moore inputs, state and outputs can be expressed by a truth table that allows for the clock delay inherent in its logic.